# how do you tune blind?

Tags: transceiver, disability

I'm about to axe the display on my radio in pursuit of cheapness.  However, I need to know, how do blind hams with older rigs tune to a station?

Comment: Hi Ben, I edited your question a bit to make it a little easier to read.  Please feel free to revert the edit, or edit it some more ;)

Comment: How does removing a part you already have contribute to cheapness?  Or is this a radio you're building?

Comment: Im at the point where im looking at kits.

Comment: This question already has been asked and answered [here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/how-do-blind-hams-operate).